# How should I extract specific words in a string in a dataframe into a different column?

Tags: python, dataframe, units-of-measurement

I have a dataset where one of the columns' rows are populated with strings with a few pieces of information, some of which I would like to extract into a different column.

Currently, I have something like this:

| name | price |
| --- | --- |
| A CERUMEN UNIDOSE B/10 AFR | 125 |
| ACARILBIAL SOL EXT FL/200ML | 8569 |
| ACCULOL 0.5% CY FL/5ML | 563 |
| ACEFLAMEX 100MG CP B/20 | 12563 |
| ACFOL 5MG COMP B/25 | 896 |

What I would like to have is a separate column for the medications that include some measurement in the name (that is, 200ml or 100mg) and if they don't, a missing value. All the measurements in the dataset are either mg, ml or g

Ideally, something like this:

| **name** | **price** | **measurement** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A CERUMEN UNIDOSE B/10 AFR | 125 | "nan" |
| ACARILBIAL SOL EXT FL/200ML | 8569 | "200ML" |
| ACCULOL 0.5% CY FL/5ML | 563 | "5ML" |
| ACEFLAMEX 100MG CP B/20 | 12563 | "100MG" |
| ACFOL 5MG COMP B/25 | 896 | "5MG" |

I tried turning the whole name column into a list of lists and transfering only the words that end in ml, mg and g into a separate list but then I could not match it back to the data frame

How should I go about doing this?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [regex](https://regex101.com/r/g28qJy/1) to the column "name".

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A CERUMEN UNIDOSE B/10 AFR', 'ACARILBIAL SOL EXT FL/200ML', 'ACCULOL 0.5% CY FL/5ML', 'ACEFLAMEX 100MG CP B/20', 'ACFOL 5MG COMP B/25'], 
                   'price': [125, 8569, 563, 12563, 896]})

df['measurement'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: re.search(r'([\d]+)(?:MG|ML)', x).group() 
if re.search(r'([\d]+)(?:MG|ML)', x) else "nan")
```

| name | price | measurement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A CERUMEN UNIDOSE B/10 AFR | 125 | nan |
| ACARILBIAL SOL EXT FL/200ML | 8569 | 200ML |
| ACCULOL 0.5% CY FL/5ML | 563 | 5ML |
| ACEFLAMEX 100MG CP B/20 | 12563 | 100MG |
| ACFOL 5MG COMP B/25 | 896 | 5MG |

You can also check pandas functions such as [extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html).